# Strange SVG path syntax used in Snap.svg tutorial?

Tags: svg, snap.svg

While looking through the [Snap.svg tutorial](http://snapsvg.io/start/), I came across the following line of code that made me do a double take:

```
// Now lets create pattern
var p = s.path("M10-5-10,15M15,0,0,15M0-5-20,15")
```

What is `M10-5-10,15`? At first, I thought it may have been some kind of coordinate-range syntax, but that wouldn't really make much sense in this case, and I couldn't find anything remotely close to that in the [SVG path spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html). I also couldn't find anything of note in the [Snap.svg docs](http://snapsvg.io/docs/).

Interestingly enough, that code does seem to [draw the desired pattern](http://jsfiddle.net/6hjyao77/)...

Answer (score 3):

The [simplest answer](http://jsfiddle.net/6hjyao77/1/) is often the right one. **There is no special syntax - the coordinates are just concatenated together with no white space.**

The clue is the command: `M` is the `moveto` command, which doesn't normally draw anything. If you look in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands), however, you'll notice the following:

> If a moveto is followed by multiple pairs of coordinates, the
>   subsequent pairs are treated as implicit lineto commands.

So, a `moveto` can actually have multiple coordinate pairs, and anything after the first pair is treated as a `lineto` command. The mystery syntax is, in reality, just a concise (but less readable) way of writing `M10,-5 -10,15 M15,0 0,15 M0,-5 -20,15`, the hyphens being the negative signs.

Simply looking at the [SVG path grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF) also shows quite clearly that the arguments to `moveto` are coordinate-pairs, and coordinates are simple numbers.

I suppose the key thing to take away is that SVG paths don't really need whitespace or commas, unless the numbers would be ambiguous without them.